# Bing Speech API for Swift on iOS

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Does anyone have the Bing Speech API for iOS working with a Swift project? The provided frameworks don't seem to import correctly when added to the project following the directions provided on the sample site.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS

Arguably there are more steps required to import an Objective-C framework into Swift, which I've tried such as using the bridging header, but have no success getting the module to be recognized or any classes in the Framework to be found.